# How can I use syms to address N different variables

Tags: matlab

I need N variables for my equation system:

```
X = cell(N,1)
for k=1:N
    X(k) = {sym('X(k)')};
end
```

After creating these variables I want to utilize them in an equation system:

```
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if i~=j
            S(i)=sum(X(j))
        end
    end
    f(i)=x(i)+2*S(i)+3
end
```

I get the error `Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments type 'cell'`. How should I define the variables `X(1),...X(N)` without using 'cell'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`sym` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) you can use eg. `A = sym('A%d%d', [2 2]);` to create a symbolic matrix.

Is this what you mean?

```
N = 5;
% Initialize symbolic matrices with proper size
X = sym('x%d', [N 1]);
S = sym(zeros(N, 1));
f = sym(zeros(N, 1));

for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if i~=j
            S(i) = S(i) + X(j);
        end
    end
    f(i)=X(i)+2*S(i)+3;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert them to a matrix using the `cell2mat` function.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html